# How can I decide whether I care about a kernel vulnerability related to IPv6?

Tags: kernel, ipv6

I've got some Ubuntu 10.04 and 12.04 systems that have an inet6 (IPv6) address. However, our firewall is configured to deny all and some pass rules are added for inet (IPv4) addresses. Do I need to care about updating our kernels when a change is made to them to address IPv6 vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your systems are not reachable using IPv6 – if the firewall drops all IPv6 connections, that is – I don't see why you should worry.

On a general note, keeping your system up to the latest security fixes is still a very good idea. Next month you might decide to use IPv6 and by then you probably have forgotten about this vulnerability – after all, it doesn't affect your system right now.

Answer (score 0):

What is the IPv6 addresses do do you talk about?

There are link local addresses that each network device get, which start with fe80::/10 (not shore about the net part, the prefix are right though.

Those are not allowed to be transfered cross routers, so these are nothing you need/can bother about. So no, don't bother. But if you have ufw(8), see to it that it also works with IPv6, then it will work with both static and IPv6- addresses.